# Function on load page in React-Native

Tags: react-native

I need to make a simple function that load webpage when open the app,

something like that

```
onLoad(https://reactnative.dev)
```

(not sure is that correct, but for example).

Can someone help with an example how can that be done?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to achive but take a look at useEffect

Comment: I want when open the app, to redirect to some web page nothing else

Comment: @YoanIvanov In your application or to browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-webview) help you

`npm i react-native-webview`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
 
// ...
class MyWebComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return <WebView source={{ uri: 'https://reactnative.dev/' }} />;
  }
}
```